# Create progressbar with just timestamp?

Tags: java, android, media-player

Would it be possible to create a progress bar that can animate time remaining of a song, based on when it began playing, and how long the song is?

For example, a int that gathers time play started, and compares again the length in ms?

I understand the concept but can't quite wrap round how to do it in my head!

Edit: To clarify, I could get the int of time remaining, and of time started, but I wouldn't know how to combine them into an animated bar and then display it in XML.

Answer (score 0):

create custom animatedProgressBar

```
public class AnimateProgressBar extends ProgressBar {

    private static final Interpolator DEFAULT_INTERPOLATER = new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator();

    private ValueAnimator animator;
    private ValueAnimator animatorSecondary;
    private boolean animate = true;

    public AnimateProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public AnimateProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AnimateProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public boolean isAnimate() {
        return animate;
    }

    public void setAnimate(boolean animate) {
        this.animate = animate;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setProgress(int progress) {
        if (!animate) {
            super.setProgress(progress);
            return;
        }
        if (animator != null)
            animator.cancel();
        if (animator == null) {
            animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(getProgress(), progress);
            animator.setInterpolator(DEFAULT_INTERPOLATER);
            animator.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    AnimateProgressBar.super.setProgress((Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue());
                }
            });
        } else
            animator.setIntValues(getProgress(), progress);
        animator.start();

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void setSecondaryProgress(int secondaryProgress) {
        if (!animate) {
            super.setSecondaryProgress(secondaryProgress);
            return;
        }
        if (animatorSecondary != null)
            animatorSecondary.cancel();
        if (animatorSecondary == null) {
            animatorSecondary = ValueAnimator.ofInt(getProgress(), secondaryProgress);
            animatorSecondary.setInterpolator(DEFAULT_INTERPOLATER);
            animatorSecondary.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    AnimateProgressBar.super.setSecondaryProgress((Integer) animation
                            .getAnimatedValue());
                }
            });
        } else
            animatorSecondary.setIntValues(getProgress(), secondaryProgress);
        animatorSecondary.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (animator != null)
            animator.cancel();
        if (animatorSecondary != null)
            animatorSecondary.cancel();
    }

}
```

in layout

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar_frame"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp">

        <my.gov.islam.smarthalal.ui.custom.AnimateProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="8dp"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:max="100"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_webview"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </FrameLayout>
```

in code, just set max of the song duration, example currentTime/totaltime * 100

```
example : currentTime = 30 seconds
          totalTime = 280 seconds

progressBar.setMax(100); // set the maximum in persentage

then, in song callback method,

progressBar.setProgress(currentTime/280 * 100);
```